# How to list terms according to another field

Tags: 8

I have two field(Entity references).  Category and feature fields.

Entity references belong to  different vocabularies.

I need to get child field terms from multiple parent field terms .

My scenario is ; Field A : Category(parent), Field B : Features(Child).

Need to get all features from multiple categories which selected from parent field..

How to filter the options from feature field according to a previous select list (Category field) ?

***What I've tried to solve***

**1-Conditional fields module.** 
I have to create more 15 fields to assign dependencies for each category. I do not want to use this option as there will be a performance problem.

**2-Business rules module**
I've tried business rules >> Dependent field with entity refenrence list option.

But It's useful only single parent selected.It shows only child terms (features) from first selected parent(category). I can't get features which belong to other categories.  I need to list multiple features from multiple parent terms selected.

Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

[image]

Comment: You may need to code a custom module to achieve this. I don't think there are any modules to provide this logic as far as I know.

Comment: @Beebee Thanks for interested. So, I have to give up..

Comment: No you can make a custom module. I didn't mean you have to give up.